# How can I export a AFP or XSL-FO file from Jasperreport

Tags: xsl-fo, afp

I am using Jasperreport to generate a report, it supports pdf, word, xml, and etc. file format, but there is no afp format, if anyone have some better solution, please tell me, thank you every much.